# BIRT: How to share reports to end user

Tags: birt

I am new to BIRT. I created a report which has pie chart and a tabular report which has drill down. I run the report locally as "View report as HTML" option it works fine. When I save the report from browser as html format, and send the link to end user. He is not able to do a drill down on the report. How does end user see the report completely ? What are the steps to be taken ? Also how do I run the report from command line ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the URLs that you are using for the drill down to see if they are available from the remote machine.